# Rails render/stream IO-like object without buffering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, networking, stream, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a controller that needs to respond with upto maybe 100MB of data that its getting from another source on the network (so e.g. a HTTP, FTP, or custom protocol socket), and I am trying to work out how I should render this response without the considerable latency of writing a temp file then rendering/sending that.

Its also important that I can "close" the stream when rails is done, so I can limit the number of active connections, or use pools (e.g. because some protocols have a slow "connect").

Passing an `IO` directly to render does not work. `render sock`

```
'#<TCPSocket:fd 20>' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object
```

For templates I saw the docs say just use `render stream: true` to disable buffering, but for that Id still need Rails to accept (and maybe buffer) my object anyway.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution would be to make use of the built-in [**live streaming support**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#live-streaming-of-arbitrary-data) in Rails with the `ActionController::Live` module:

> Rails allows you to stream more than just files. In fact, you can stream anything you would like in a response object. The `ActionController::Live` module allows you to create a persistent connection with a browser. Using this module, you will be able to send arbitrary data to the browser at specific points in time.

```
class MyController < ActionController::Base
  include ActionController::Live

  def my_action
    response.headers["Content-Type"] = "your/content-type"

    TCPSocket.open("server", 1234) do |socket|
      # for each chunk of data you read:
      response.stream.write data
    end
  ensure
    response.stream.close
  end
end
```

Comment: Ah that looks good. Must have missed that somewhere since "ActionController::Live" never came up while searching and checking references :)